# Dimension of Domain and Range via Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been struggling to prove the following result, which seems pretty intuitive.

Suppose we have a $m\times n$ matrix $A$. Further suppose that column vectors of $A$ form an orthonormal set in $\mathbb{F}^m$ and row vectors form and orthonormal set in $\mathbb{F}^n$. How can we show that $m = n$? I have tried using  rank-nullity theorem but to no avail.

Comment: Do you know the definition of an orthonormal set? Likewise, do you know the definition of the range/column space of a matrix, and the domain/row space?

Comment: Column space (range)  is the space spanned by the column vectors, similarly row space is the space spanned by the rows.

Comment: A useful result here is that if $A:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and $n>m$ then there is some $x\neq 0$ such that $Ax = 0$. Also, you just need linear independence.

Comment: I think I can see it now. I am sorry if this is silly. Since row/column vectors are linearly independent (follows from orthonormality), then $\mathbb{F}^n = span(\text{row vectors})$ and $\mathbb{F}^m = span(\text{column vectors})$. Consequently, we can use the fact that row rank equals column rank to conclude that $m = n$.